# Replicate light effects with transparency

Tags: css, html

as a medium of learning I try to replicate some things I see in the Internet. A friend of mine that knows what am I doing, saw a [template](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39011.html) and asked me to replicate part of it for his web page, I already have most of what I needed from the template, but the thing he liked the most I tried and failed and I am not understanding  what is the magic involved in this template...

What I need is to replicate the main sheet transparency and the light effect behind it, the transparency I made was with a black 1x1 png made on the GIMP(I can't buy the Photoshop) I also have a nice pattern like in the template since it is one of the things my friend asked...

[image: transparent box with light effect made with the GIMP]

this is the effect I want, I tried messing around with shadows, but didn't get what i wanted I ended up deleting the code, now all I have is this:

HTML:

```
 <body>
 <div id="box"></div>
 <div id="light"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#light{
border:solid 0px white;
height:550px;
width:800px;
left:50%;
margin-top:130px;
margin-left:-400px;
z-index:-1000;
position:absolute;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #929292;
border-radius:100px;
background-color:#929292;
opacity:0.4;
}
#box{
background-image:url(../images/shtr.png);
margin:0px auto 0px;
width:1060px;
height:auto;
border:solid 0px white;
}
```

i don't know if i need to use jquery or javascript, or if that would help in the page performance...

Comment: There are a few effects in that picture, are you after the background texture, or the light to dark transition? It might help to see a shot of the original part as well, to aid you in your problem.

Comment: the texture is mine, I want the light to dark transition thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done, i created a new div that casts a shadow, placed it outside of the screen(left:100%;) and the shadow is casted to the center with the color #CECECE the HTML code:

```
<div id="light"></div>
<div id="box">
    ( ... content ... )
</div>
```

in the CSS :

```
#light{
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 800px;
width: 840px;
z-index:-1000;
opacity:0.15;
}  

#box{
background-image:url(../images/shtr.png);/*black 50-60% transparent 1x1 image*/
margin:0px auto 0px;
width:1060px;
height:auto;
border:solid 0px white;
}
```

and to cast the shadow I used a jQuery script, via only css it wasn't working i don't know exactly why... the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var A = -myWidth - 49.5*myWidth/60
    $("#brilho_grande").css("box-shadow", A+"px 0px 10000px 100px #CECECE");
    $("#brilho_grande").css("left", 2*myWidth+"px");
    $("#brilho_grande").css("top", "339px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some CSS3 things you can do here.

The first thing you need to do is setup the divs with the texture and highlights. The div with the highlight should ideally be a child of the textured div.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="transp"></div>
</div>
```

Next you need to apply the effects and backgrounds to the correct elements:

CSS:

```
.wrap
{
  background: url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/35/83/02/pattern-patterns_00358302.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.transp
{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fTAH/

Comment: I tryed that, but we can see the light transition under the div, if you see in the template link it is possible to see the gradient under the div, like if the div was illuminating the background, and we can tell nearly where the light source is, this is a really nice and clever trick thats why I am seeking for help so I can learn more :)

Comment: You just have to adjust the values in the rgba and box-shadow properties. Also, you could add a very subtle radial gradient to the inner div itself, but support for this is low.

Comment: but is it possible to say that the shadow will start from inside the div and spread outside?

Comment: No, that's not the way shadows work in CSS. But it can be faked with radial gradients and some clever color matching :)